# What is the correct way to extend a grunt task based on a few others?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I currently am creating a custom Grunt task for my application. It does several things, and in order to achieve these, I use a few existing Grunt tasks.

Below is how I have chosen to create my task, by aggregating these others.What I would like to know, is this a common way of extending a task or is there a better way?

Functionally it works, but I some how feel this is a hack?

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mkdir');

    var _ = require('lodash'); 

    var options = this.options();

    grunt.registerTask('custom-task-name', 'Custom task description', function () {

        // Config ommited for brevity.
        grunt.initConfig({
            clean:  { 
            },
            mkdir: { 
            },
            copy: { 
            },
            shell: { 
            },
        });

        var tasks = ['clean', 'mkdir:target', 'copy:target', 'shell:target'];

        grunt.task.run(tasks);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`grunt.registerTask` is commonly used with an array of subtasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'concat', 'copy', 'watch']);
```

**References**

- [grunt.task.registerTask](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask)